# Duplicated rows in response with engine - Merge

Tags: clickhouse

I have 3 tables `events_0`, `events_1`, `events_2` with Engine = `MergeTree`

and 1 table `events` with Engine = `Merge`

```
CREATE TABLE events as events_0 ENGINE=Merge(currentDatabase(), '^events');
```

When I run sql query like

```
select uuid from events where uuid = 'XXXX-YYY-ZZZZ';
```

I've got a duplicated response

```
┌─uuid──────────┐
│ XXXX-YYY-ZZZZ │
└───────────────┘
┌─uuid──────────┐
│ XXXX-YYY-ZZZZ │
└───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `_table` to the select clause to see which table was generating the data.

```
select _table, uuid from events where uuid = 'XXXX-YYY-ZZZZ';
```

It looks like a self-recursion to me. You might need to rename the merge table that won't be matched by regex `^events`

Comment: I understood where's I've got duplicates
Because i have 3 materialized views like `events_0_mv`, `events_1_mv`, `events_2_mv` and forgot about them